# slurm job scheduler sacct show only pending and running jobs no prolog

Tags: slurm

I am quite new to slurm.  I am looking on how to display ONLY current running and pending jobs, no prolog.

```
> sacct -s PD,R 
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
5049168       SRR600493    general cluster_u+          1    RUNNING      0:0 
5049168.0        prolog            cluster_u+          1  COMPLETED      0:0
```

Why is it printing the prolog and what the prolog is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `squeue` for that, rather than `sacct`. `squeue` will list running and pending jobs, and will be able to display more information (requested resources, etc.) than `sacct`. And `squeue` will not show job steps (like 'prolog' here)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a job with slurm there are two things that happen. First, it allocates resources and then when you launch something on this resource, it creates a step.

So the two lines you are showing belong to the same job. The first line is the allocation and the second is the first step. So someone launched a step with a binary named prolog, this step is now finished but the allocation of the resource is not released. The user probably ran `salloc` first and then `srun`.

If you think that nobody launched a binary named prolog it's maybe that you have configured a prolog on slurm to be run at each first step of a job.